# Filezilla+Wordpress weird behaviour

Tags: wordpress, sftp, filezilla

Every time I edit a php file(child theme template page) and upload it via Filezilla, then I download the same file just to check if the changes are there (which they are). But after purging the cache (wp-engine), clear cache theme and clearing the cache in browser, the changes won't reflect in the website.

But here is the weird part, after downloading the edited file just to double check if the changes are there (which they still are) and after some time (maybe 12 hrs) I downloaded the same file and changes are gone. It is back from the original state after I've done the editing!

Any ideas what the hell is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Either filezilla is unable to actually overwrite the file on your site when it saves the changes or purging the cache is somehow reverting to a previous version. Make sure you set filezilla to overwrite existing files and/or try not purging the cache and try to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Noted Sir. I'll try to do that to pin point the problem. Thanks. Will update you later.

Comment: No dice sir. I've tried every combination. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am not an expert on child themes. Just from what you are describing it would seem that there is something going wrong with the implementation of the child theme. Maybe someone else on here can lend a hand...

Comment: I think so too. The previous developer got something wrong I think. Just bad luck that it lands on me. Thanks for the help mike.